# Is there any significance to Linux device major numbers besides being essentially an index into a table?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Confused by the significance of device major numbers.  Could someone please confirm this for me?:

Linux device major numbers are simply indexes into some kernel list like data structure (~an array) and carry no real significance beyond that. Essentially some object implementing some set of interfaces (driver) lives at that offset. By convention certain major numbers point to such object with certain roles, but its only convention. For example, I had always assumed major numbers were somehow associated with specific hardware addresses / busses, but that is not the case - they are just indexes ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a versioning strategy.

Comment: This question is not about versioning strategy. I don't even know what that is. Please help me understand how I have managed to ask a question about versioning strategy.

Comment: your asking why linux is doing something - that sort of question is off topic for here.

Comment: I'm asking a question about how Linux works, not *why*. I don't care why.

Comment: Do you mean major *device* numbers? I think some of the commenters are assuming (not unreasonably) that you're talking about the version number of the Linux kernel (e.g., 3.13.0 where the major version number is 3). I suggest updating your question to make it clearer what you're asking about.

Comment: @KeithThompson Ah thx. Your right that was confusing. I mean *device* major number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the major device numbers, you're essentially correct: they index into the kernel's device driver table to identify driver routines for handling the device. The minor device numbers though, distinguish unique devices that use that driver from each other, as multiple devices could be present on the system that utilize a single driver.

You're also correct that some major numbers are statically (hard-coded) allocated to certain common devices like your hard disk or some TTY devices (for legacy reasons), but most are allocated dynamically. New drivers that are added to the Linux kernel are now expected to request device numbers dynamically.

Further Reading:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt - Shows which kinds of devices are hard-coded to which major numbers
http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=94 - More detailed explanation of major/minor numbers.